# Old power supply regulation board will not trim to spec

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator

I have an old voltage controlled synthesizer that relies on accurate power supply voltages (+/-) for everything to run in tune and so it can interface to other similar instruments.  Yesterday I opened it up and replaced the 35 year old power supply rectifiers and caps as maintenance.  At that time realized that the board was set at 9.64v.  Even when maxed out, the board would only reach 9.97v.  I feel that the board should regulate at the proper 10.000v spec with the trimmers around their mid point. My best guess is precision resistors (R39,34,44) drifted over the years?

The pic of the board shows the top left trimmer (R21) at factory position (9.64v) and when fully CCW, only got me to 9.97v

[image: Schematic]

[Link to full size schematic](http://s83.photobucket.com/user/srmaietta/media/photo-3.jpg.html)

[image: Description 1]
[image: Description 2] 
[image: Regulator board]

Comment: "only got me to 9.97v" - Most cheap voltmeters are not accurate to 0.3%/30mV ...

Comment: What voltmeter did you use?

Comment: Wavetek Meterman 220.  Not lab grade by any means, I know. Here's the DC voltage spec: Accuracy: All Ranges ±(0.25% rdg +2dgts)This whole issue has kicked me into finally purchasing a decent bench top DMM/Counter.  Still, the trimmer is pegged!

Comment: I would start by replacing the Zener. Then check all the resistors.

Comment: Will do.  Some of those resistors are very close spec so I'm going to check them for sure.  I didn't think diodes really degrade over time, but for a buck or two part I'll swap it out.

Comment: @SteveMaietta They sure do degrade. I replace zeners in PSUs as a matter of course. Mostly they're OK but sometimes they drift around amazingly. As this one is the voltage reference and you're on the edge of the adjustment range it would be my first choice.

Comment: There has, as yet, been no disussion of actually checking the output of the zener. Just trying to be the voice of reason here - so far, everything appears to be in tolerance. Don't add ketchup to the steak without tasting it first.

Comment: EJP, thanks for that tidbit.  I found some of these zeners and they're on their way. Sean I agree with you entirely.  I ordered a bench top DMM to be more accurate and precise with things like this and as soon as it arrives I will begin to investigate further.  Thanks for some starting points gents!